# animate function of jquery crashes the browser

Tags: jquery, browser, crash, jquery-animate

The problem is with animate function of jquery on 5th line from last, if i remove that line it works fine, otherwise it crashes the browser{firefox especially}, but i need that animate function to make user aware of new updates... can any one pls tell me why the animate function is crashing the browser???

```
function doAnimation() {

    var newUpdate = newUpdates.updates[updateIterator] != null ? newUpdates.updates[updateIterator] : null;
    var update = "";

    while (newUpdate != null) {

        if (updateIterator == 0) {
            $(".nodata").hide();
        }

        lastupdateTime = newUpdate.lastUpdate;



        update += "<div class='live-updates-data'><img width='48px' height='48px'  class='" + newUpdate.clientId + "' src='company_logo/thumb/" + newUpdate.img + "' align='logo' onerror='showDefaultimage(this);' /><h2><span>" + newUpdate.title + "</span></h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' class='" + newUpdate.clientId + " mp'> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; Join Chat &nbsp;</a><p>" + newUpdate.updateMessage + "</p></div>";

        updateIterator++;
        newUpdate = newUpdates.updates[updateIterator] != null ? newUpdates.updates[updateIterator] : null;




    } // end of while
    // after finishing the while loop
    if (update != "") {
        $("#shoutBox").prepend(update);
        $("#shoutBox div:first-child").animate({
            "height": "toggle"
        }, "slow", "linear");
    }
    oTimeout = setTimeout(getShouts, timoutSpeed); //Again start the timout function to ge  
    updateIterator = 0;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes i am its "linear", this animate function was like this before 


$("#shoutBox div:first-child").animate({ "height": "toggle" }, 1, "linear", function () 
    {
                   $("#shoutBox div:first-child").animate({ "height": "toggle" }, "slow", "linear", function () 
       {
      //updateIterator++;
           // setTimeout(doAnimation,5000);
           });
      }); 
      }
then i changed it to 



 $("#shoutBox div:first-child").animate({ "height": "toggle" }, "slow", "linear");

Comment: while crashing, browser is giving error , that some script has stoped working or are unresponsive in jquery.js file

Answer (score 0):

this will continuously fire `$(".nodata").hide();` which will append in jquery animation queue.
write this as...

```
if (updateIterator === 0 && !$(".nodata").is(":hidden")) {
            $(".nodata").hide();
}
```

Comment: But why to use `while` loop here?

Comment: i removed that while loop, but that wasn't the problem, it was something else :P